# QT: Getting text content from web page

Tags: qt, qtnetwork

I've been trying to start with a simple app that retrieves data from a simple HTML page upon clicking a button and stumbled upon a rather helpful [tutorial](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Download_Data_from_URL) on QT-Project and have been trying to implement it for my own project.

Everything manages to compile until I try to actually try to implement the loadImage function (as found in the tutorial). (I actually had to initialize `m_pImgCtrl` as `Filedownloader * m_pImgCtrl = new FileDownloader(imageUrl, this);` and I'm not exactly sure how it's suppose to work without prior object declaration?)

From what I get, `m_pImgCtrl` isn't actually defined in the `loadImage()` function since it is initialized outside of the function? Or does the `connect()` function do something that I'm not too aware of?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial doesn't tell you the whole story.

The code in section **Usage** is supposed to be part of a class `MainWindow` – the controller of your main window (see line 1 of tutorial's last snippet).  This class contains a slot `loadImaged()` called when the NetworkReply has finished. It also has a member `FileDownloader * m_pImgCtrl`.

For instance, the second Usage snippet could be part of a slot `MainWindow::buttonClicked()` like

```
void MainWindow::buttonClicked()
{
    QUrl imageUrl("http://qt.digia.com/Documents/1/QtLogo.png");
    m_pImgCtrl = new FileDownloader(imageUrl, this);
    connect(m_pImgCtrl, SIGNAL(downloaded()), SLOT(loadImage()));
}
```

Comment: hey chrizke thanks for mentioning that. Now it does make sense, compile and should theoretically run but I'm getting a "Class QNSListener is implemented in both /.../libqcorewlanbearer and /.../libqcorewlanbearer_debug.dylib One of the two should be used. Which one is undefined." error report. Apparently it's supposed to be a bug issue? Do you perhaps have any experience with that?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Qt version 5.0.x. See [here](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-27908).