# (QtNetwork) Data is not returned / network reply empty

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qtnetwork, qnetworkrequest

As a follow-up to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350651/qt-getting-text-content-from-web-page) I asked, I'm now faced with the problem that the downloaded data is empty even though the requested page exists (at least from the web browser it does).

I'm guessing the data is actually downloaded cause the debug line at `fileDownloaded()` is called and the signal from `downloaded()` is then passed on to the `SLOT(loadText()` which then prints to console the `"STRING: "` line every time the button is clicked

*mainwindow.h*

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QTextCodec>
#include <QDebug>

using namespace std;

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class DataFetch : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit DataFetch(QUrl url, QObject *parent=0);
    virtual ~DataFetch();

    QByteArray downloadedData() const;
signals:
    void downloaded();

public slots:
    void fileDownloaded(QNetworkReply* reply);

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager m_webManager;
    QByteArray m_downloaded;
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    DataFetch * m;

public slots:
    void btnClickHandler();

private slots:
    void loadText();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};





#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

*mainwindow.cpp*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


DataFetch::DataFetch(QUrl url, QObject *parent):
    QObject(parent)
{
    connect(&m_webManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), SLOT(fileDownloaded(QNetworkReply*)));
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    m_webManager.get(request);
}

DataFetch::~DataFetch() { }

void DataFetch::fileDownloaded(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    QByteArray m_downloaded = reply->readAll();
    qDebug() << "received reply";
    reply->deleteLater();
    emit downloaded();
}

QByteArray DataFetch::downloadedData() const
{
    return m_downloaded;
}

void MainWindow::loadText()
{
    cout << "STRING: " << m->downloadedData().data() << endl;
    ui->lblText->setText(m->downloadedData());
}

void MainWindow::btnClickHandler()
{
    QUrl textURL = QUrl("http://192.168.2.7/index.html");
    m = new DataFetch(textURL, this);
    connect(m, SIGNAL(downloaded()), SLOT(loadText()));
}
```

*main.cpp* remains unchanged from default template..

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: connect to the error() signal and see if it's emitted

Comment: In `void DataFetch::fileDownloaded(QNetworkReply *reply)` put this `qDebug() << reply->readAll();` and see what happens.